# switch to system version with sdkman

Tags: sdkman

With `nvm` you can go like this to fall back on the system version if installed:

```
nvm use system
```

Is there anything similar for sdkman? either to turn off a single application (something like `sdk use ant system` or turn off sdkman completely

Comment: There is a Github issue related with this feature: https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/673

Answer (score 4):

sdkman's approach to use system versions is [Local Versions](https://sdkman.io/usage#localversion).

You have to install a new version pointing to your system installation:

```
$ sdk install ant system /usr/lib/share/ant
```

Then use that version as any other sdkman candidate:

```
$ sdk use ant system
```